# How does recursion work with Java 8 Stream?

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, java-stream

I have a method like this where I'm using recursion with Streams:

```
  private static List<Member> convertToFlatList(List<Member> memberList)
  {
    return memberList.stream().flatMap(i -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(i), convertToFlatList(i.getChildren()).stream())).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

Lets say a `Member` class has a children list of members that is always initialized to an empty list. Here what I'm doing is converting the hierarchical list of members to a flat list. I understand that part. What I don't understand is how recursion works here.

In recursion, it's terminated when certain conditions are met. But here I'm not giving any condition for terminating intentionally. So how does the termination part work here?

Comment: Ends once you iterate over all the items in memberList.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The recursion will end when `memberList` will be empty, since at this case an empty `List` will be returned.

i.e. when `i.getChildren()` is an empty `List`, the recursive call `convertToFlatList(i.getChildren())` will receive an empty `List`, so the `Stream` pipeline won't make another recursive call (since it has no elements to execute `flatMap` on), and will return an empty `List`.

Answer (score 8):

The termination happens because for the "leafs" that don't have any children,

```
Stream.concat(Stream.of(i), convertToFlatList(i.getChildren()).stream())
```

will invoke `convertToFlatList` on an empty list, and applying `flatMap()` on an empty stream does not invoke the mapping operation.